# Auto Layout: Toolbar not shown, container views distorted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit, autolayout

I am using the following auto layout settings on my container view, which contains a toolbar positioned at the top and two container views with the same height each:

[image]

Toolbar:

[image]

Container 1:

[image]

Container 2:

[image]

However, the result is completely distorted, the toolbar is not shown. The container contents are mixed together. I don't get any warnings or errors.

[image]

Any idea on what might be wrong?